# Validar imagen JPG o PNG PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Bueno el punto es que no se como validar lo siguiente, en la base de datos capturo la url de una imagen y después la muestro con un `echo` en php, lo que intento hacer es que me valide la imagen ya sea jpg o png para después exportarlo en un archivo de excel y que me aparezca la imagen, para ello estoy usando la librería de exportación PHPExcel y es donde se me complica, funciona unicamente si manejo jpg o png pero no los 2 a la vez que es lo que trato de hacer a través de una validación... código en la librería:

```
//Consulta
$sqli=mysqli_query($conn, "select logo from perfil where idperfil = 1");
foreach ($sqli as $key => $value) {
    $value['logo']; //ruta de la imagen 
}
?>

<img class="img-responsive" name="imagefile" id="imagefile" src="<?php echo "../".$value['logo']?>" alt="Logo"> //mostrando la imagen
<?php

$fila = 7; //Establecemos en que fila inciara a imprimir los datos

//Validación de imagen en png o jpeg Aqui falla, solo puedo utilizar 1

if($_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/jpg"){

$gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg("../".$value['logo']);//Logotipo JPG

}elseif($_FILES["imagefile"]["type"] == "image/png"){

$gdImage = imagecreatefrompng("../".$value['logo']);//Logotipo JPG
}
```

Comment: Has probado en vez de usar el elseif usar solo dos ifs separados? porque si se cumple la condicion del jpg no entrará en la condicion del png, si los haces por separado debería entrar en los dos y hacerlos 'a la vez' como dices tu

Comment: Lo cambie a utilizar if por separado gracias :9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te ocurre porque no usas bien los condicionales [IF](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.if.php) y [ELSEIF](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.elseif.php).

> La primera expresión elseif (si hay alguna) que se evalúe como TRUE
>   sería ejecutada.

Tu código podría quedar así:

```
//Validación de imagen en png o jpeg Aqui falla, solo puedo utilizar 1

if($_FILES['imagefile']['type'] == "image/jpg"){

   $gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg("../".$value['logo']);//Logotipo JPG

}
if($_FILES["imagefile"]["type"] == "image/png"){

   $gdImage = imagecreatefrompng("../".$value['logo']);//Logotipo PNG
}
```

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo lo resolví de la siguiente manera, como no puedo obtener del todo la imagen y obtener las propiedades, unicamente tengo la URL en la base de datos donde la almaceno (`../vistas/img/perfil/15_log2.jpg`), decidí extraer los los últimos 3 caracteres de la cadena URL quedandome como resultado (`jpg` o `png`) dependiendo de lo que venga en la consulta, y de esa manera logre que funcionara.

```
//Substracion de formato jpg png

$sub=substr($value['logo'], -3);  //Aqui extraigo los ultimos 3 caracteres de la cadena

//Validacion de imgen en png o jpeg

if($sub == "jpg"){

    $gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg("../".$value['logo']);//Logotipo JPG

}

if($sub == "png"){

    $gdImage = imagecreatefrompng("../".$value['logo']);//Logotipo PNG
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ojala te sirva.

```
 ext = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
                if (strtolower($ext[1]) == "png" || strtolower($ext[1]) == "jpg" || strtolower($ext[1]) == "pdf") {
                } else {
                    echo "El archivo adjunto solo acepta pdf, jpg y png.<br>";
                    exit;
                }
```